# power-shell command line execute cmd on remote computer

Tags: powershell

Dears.

I've two computer, a host and a client
And connect with LAN cable.

But I've cmd .bat file need execute on client computer through host computer.
What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Read [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/Running-Remote-Commands?view=powershell-6) for help running remote commands.

Comment: I've tried command invoke-command -computername computer, but found error meesage, The WinRM client can't process request..............

Comment: Have a look at [this page](https://serverfault.com/questions/657918/remote-ps-session-fails-on-non-domain-server) to enable WinRM on server / client.

Comment: tried this command, Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "Computer1,Computer2"
And check (don't need Admin for that)

Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts                                                           

But stil can't work . show error message

The client can't connect to the destination sepcified  in the request......

Comment: Now show error message : Access is denied

Comment: Are you running PowerShell as administrator? Following the steps in that post worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the remote computer, open a PS ADMINISTRATOR console, and execute this:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

Then return to your system and try again.